# Word VBS script add border cell

Tags: ms-word, vbscript, cell

I have a simple VBS script below that opens Word and creates a table with 4 cells, I need to add a bottom border only for the cell with TEXT inside and not for the entire table, any ideas?

```
Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
objword.visible = true
Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Add()
Set objSelection = objWord.Selection
Set objRange = objDoc.Range()
objDoc.Tables.Add objRange,2,2
Set objTable = objDoc.Tables(1)
objTable.Cell(2,1).Range.Font.Name = "Arial"
objTable.Cell(2,1).Range.Text = "TEXT"
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I add internal borders to a Word table after encountering an error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8132584/how-can-i-add-internal-borders-to-a-word-table-after-encountering-an-error)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
objTable.Cell(2,1).Borders(-3).LineStyle = 1 'wdLineStyleSingle
```

Comment: Prefer `Const wdLineStyleSingle = 1` and use the constant.